# Restructuring a list of lists in python

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, sum

I am trying to combine several elements from a list of lists in Python3. I have a dataset simplified as:

```
example_list = [
    [1, +, 3, "MNP1", 2480],
    [2, +, 2, "MNP1", 2480],
    [3, +, 1, "MNP2", 3200],
    [4, -, 4, "MNP3", 2480],
    [5, -, 2, "MNP4", 4700]
]
```

What I need is to generate a new list of lists of four elements containing:

1st element: each different value of the last element of the example. If they have different symbol (+ or -) have to be considered separately (ex:2480, 3200, 2480, 4700)

2nd element: each symbol

3rd element: number of times the last element appears (2, 1, 1, 1)

4th element: the sum of third elements only if the symbol and the last element are the same (3+2, 1, 4, 2)

The expected output is:

```
 output_list = [
[2480, +, 2, 5],
[3200, +, 1, 1],
[2480, -, 1, 4],
[4700, -, 1, 2]
]
```

I have been trying several ways to do it using dictionaries with the last element as key but I am not able to make the function consider the symbol.

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you explain that last position again? Why 5, 1, 4, 2?

Comment: Is the sum of the values in third position of the example list in list when the symbol and last position in example match between lists. In that case: [1, +, 3, "MNP1", 2480], [2, +, 2, "MNP1", 2480] as they share the symbol and the 2480, in the output I need to sum their third elements (3+2)=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to group the entries by their second and last column. If order is important, use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), otherwise a regular dictionary might work as well.

```
example_list = [
    [1, '+', 3, "MNP1", 2480],
    [2, '+', 2, "MNP1", 2480],
    [3, '+', 1, "MNP2", 3200],
    [4, '-', 4, "MNP3", 2480],
    [5, '-', 2, "MNP4", 4700]
]

output_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
for _, op, arg2, _, num in example_list:
    key = num, op
    output_dict.setdefault(key, [0, 0])
    output_dict[key][0] += 1
    output_dict[key][1] += arg2
```

Once you have that, you can turn it into a list:

```
>>> output_list = [list(key) + value for key, value in output_dict.iteritems()]
>>> print(output_list)
[['+', 2480, 2, 5], ['+', 3200, 1, 1], ['-', 2480, 1, 4], ['-', 4700, 1, 2]]
```